# Calling js function when product save button is clicked?

Tags: magento-1.9

I added new js file custom.js. What i want is to call a function when **Save** or **Save And Continue Edit** button is clicked. I am trying different things but its not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this way:

Lets assume you want to trigger your custom function on product save and edit button clicked.

Check this `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit.php` file and find this code:

```
        if (!$this->getProduct()->isReadonly()) {
            $this->setChild('save_and_edit_button',
                $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/widget_button')
                    ->setData(array(
                        'label'     => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Save and Continue Edit'),
                        'onclick'   => 'saveAndContinueEdit(\''.$this->getSaveAndContinueUrl().'\')',
                        'class' => 'save'
                    ))
            );
        }
```

Now you can just replace this line:

```
'onclick'   => 'saveAndContinueEdit(\''.$this->getSaveAndContinueUrl().'\')',
```

with this:

```
'onclick'   => 'saveAndContinueEdit(\''.$this->getSaveAndContinueUrl().'\'); myFunction();',
```

You should have your custom function as `myFunction();` in that page to be called.

This should work.